# Epi-week method for JAVA

Tags: java, date, week-number, weekday

i need to get the epi-week of a given date,so it'd be very helpful if there is a method or api to achieve this for Java.

The definition for epi-week is the following "The first epi week of the year ends, by definition, on the first Saturday of January, as long as it falls at least four days into the month. Each epi week begins on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday."

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can translate it to:

- start of week = Sunday
- minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4

For Java pre 8, the class `java.util.GregorianCalendar` defines methods like [setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek-int-) and [setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setFirstDayOfWeek-int-)

For Java-8, you can refer to the class [WeekFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#of-java.time.DayOfWeek-int-)

**Update due to question in comment:**

```
GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar(2013, Calendar.DECEMBER, 29);
gcal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
gcal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
int epiWeek = gcal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println("epi-week=" + epiWeek); // epi-week=1
```

Comment: Just to note: The week range is 1-52, in some few years like 2014 also until 53 - see for example [this website](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/mrwr-rhrr/2014/w53/index-eng.php).

Comment: Hi,thanks for answering this is the code that i have so far     
calendar.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4);
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);                                                                  The problem is that does not work  as expected for example Dec. 29 of 2013 must be in the first week of 2014 but the program says that is the 53th according to this page http://www.cmmcp.org/2014EPI.htm

Comment: @AbdielChaverriMontero See my update. The website you cited and the program example given in my update both report the week-number 1 for the date 2013-12-29.

Comment: Ok,perhaps  i misunderstood something, ill try again to be sure

Comment: @AbdielChaverriMontero Sorry that I have forgotten to press the "Save Edits"-button after writing the update where I show the code proving that `java.util.Calendar`-api proving week-number is 1 for date 2013-12-29.